# Please reopen the question

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Please reopen this question:

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/examples-of-romance-borrowings-in-proto-slavi

Answer (score 6):

Certainly insulting other users, especially moderators, isn't going to help you getting your point across, and actually it's not putting you in a good position.

Your question is not OK for the standards on the SE sites. Fix it, and I'll gladly reopen. If you want help, you can ask for it here.

If the question stays as is, the answer is no.

**Edit**: The question has been deleted.